# Image Preview (thumbnail) doesn't show after preload an image in dropzonejs

Tags: javascript, image, angularjs, upload, dropzone.js

I have a form that gets a name and an image (logo). I'm using angularjs as client side language and dropzonejs as image upload library. when the user clicks on Edit, I want him to see the image preview that he has uploaded previously. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666872/how-do-i-preload-images-into-dropzone-js) for doing so.
The problem is if I upload a new image after I preload the initial image, I couldn't see new image's preview.
here is my preload image code. (There is an angular directive for it)

```
if(scope.initialFileAddress != null && scope.initialFileAddress != "")
      mockFile = {name: scope.initialFileName, size: 1000, type: "image/jpeg"}
      this.addFile.call(this, mockFile)
      this.options.thumbnail.call(this, mockFile, scope.initialFileAddress)
```

Comment: I also get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': The argument is not a Blob.

Comment: This method(readAsDataURL) is called in createThumbnail function in dropzonejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in this line of code:

```
this.addFile.call(this, mockFile)
```

I should replace it with:

```
this.options.addedfile.call(this, mockFile)
```

This way this image is not added to the main list of files that will be uploaded. For my case this change did the work!